# Как мне сделать что б у меня в папке читались под папки, а то у меня не грузятся команды а если он просто в папке cmds тогда грузятся. discord js

Tags: javascript, discord

```
  if(err) console.log(err);
  let jsfiles = files.filter(f => f.split(".").pop() === "js");
  if(jsfiles.length <=0) console.log("Нет комманд для загрузки!!!");
  console.log(`Загружено ${jsfiles.length} комманд`);
  jsfiles.forEach((f,i) => {
    let props = require(`./cmds/${f}`);
    console.log(`${i+1}.${f} Загружен`);
    client.commands.set(props.help.name,props);
  })
});
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.

Answer (score 0):

Чтобы реализовать данный метод, вам необходимо создать самовызывающую функцию.

```js
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const fs = require('fs');

const client = new Discord.Client(/* INTENTS */);

client.commands = new Discord.Collection();

function LoadCommands(directory = "./commands") {
    fs.readdir(directory, (error, files) => {
        if (error) return console.error(error);

        const JSFiles = files.filter(file => file.split('.').pop() === 'js');
        const DIRs = files.filter(file => fs.lstatSync(`${directory}/${file}`).isDirectory()); // <- Получаем все папки.

        JSFiles.forEach(file => {
            let props = require(`${directory}/${file}`);
            client.commands.set(props.help.name, props);
        });

        DIRs.forEach(dir => { // <- Пробегаемся по каждой папке.
            LoadCommands(`${directory}/${dir}`); // <- Проверяем вложенные папки.
        });
    });
};

LoadCommands();
```